# Whats wrote with this break;

Tags: javascript, break

After adding `break`, my code no longer works.

```
alert("Warning: Game is made for the age of 18 and over.");
var a = prompt("Are you ready to enter this game?");
if (a == "yes") {alert("Entering");}
else if (a == "no") {while(true)
var a = prompt("Are you ready to enter this game?");
if(a == "yes") {break; alert("Entering");} }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by putting a break right there?  Perhaps try looking up usage examples.  This is not correct.

Comment: stop the while(true)

Comment: but you're stopping it before your alert("Entering").  Your alert will never be reached.  If that's the only piece you're missing, just try doing alert("Entering"); break;

Comment: What language is this?  Please tag your question with the appropriate programming language.  I'm guessing JavaScript.

Comment: Please properly indent the code. It might even help you understand it yourself.

Comment: if i put it after break doesnt help

Comment: I do understand it

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors in your JavaScript. You are missing out on a curly brace. The `break` statement needs to be after the `alert` statement. See the following snippet after the fixes and try to learn your mistakes.

```js
alert("Warning: Game is made for the age of 18 and over.");
var a = prompt("Are you ready to enter this game?");
if (a == "yes") {alert("Entering");}
else if (a == "no") {
  while(true) {
    //var b = prompt("Are you ready to enter this game?");
    if(a == "yes") {
        alert("Entering");
        break;
      }
  } 
}
```

Comment: this doesnt fulfill the purpose

Comment: If it doesn't, I have misunderstood your purpose. Please elaborate on what you want to achieve. Make you sure you don't represent an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you intend to prompt the user repeatedly until he answers `yes`. In that case, use this code:

```js
alert("Warning: Game is made for the age of 18 and over.");

let response = "";
while(response !== "yes") {
    response = prompt("Are you ready to enter this game?");
}

alert("Entering");
```

Comment: can you explainthis ?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> break; alert("Entering");
> ```

It's to late to `alert` after `break`ing as it immediately exits the loop and doesn't execute instruction after itself there.